# how to execute a trigger everyday at once in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

we are doing a project on microbanking and we need to calculate the interest rate in database level. So we used procedures and triggers for that. but the trigger needs to execute everyday at once to perform below given procedure. Can you provide a solution to create that trigger. Thanks in advance

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure addFDInterestToAccount(in account_number bigint(20))
BEGIN
declare interest float default 0;
declare account_type varchar(10);
declare rate float;
declare savings_account bigint(20);

start transaction;
select balance from fd_account where account_no = account_number into interest;
SELECT plan_id from fd_account where account_no = account_number into account_type;
SELECT saving_account_no from fd_account where account_no = account_number into savings_account;
select interest_rate from fd_plan where plan_id = account_type into rate;
set interest = interest*rate/1200;

insert into transaction (transaction_id, account_no, credit_debit, date_time, amount, type_, agent_id, is_fee)  values (null, savings_account, 'debit', now(), interest, 'not_special', null, false);
update account set balance = balance + interest where account_no = savings_account;
commit;
END //
DELIMITER ;

call addFDInterestToAccount(90842311);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use triggers only...why don't you think about task scheduler or windows service?

Comment: Im using mariadb, and i need to use triggers. thanks for the reply @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @AhkamNaseek - You possibly need `FOR UPDATE` on the end of each `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your requirement, I think you can use **SQL Events** for this. The general syntax goes like this,

```
 CREATE [OR REPLACE]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER | role | CURRENT_ROLE }]
    EVENT 
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    event_name    
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'comment']
    DO sql_statement;

schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  | EVERY interval 
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...] 
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
              DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

You can modify/use  following code for achiving this,

```
 CREATE EVENT example
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO call addFDInterestToAccount(90842311);
```

For further information you can vist the link [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/events/)

Also make sure you run this query before running the event

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: thanx for the reply @jinesh Shah. But the problem is i need to do this process for all accounts in the "account" table. So using events, after 'DO' can we call a trigger or something for that

Comment: In that case, you either have to modify your procedure or event. I would recommend you to remove parameter while calling parameter and in the procedure fetch all the account number by select statement, then take a **Cursor** which will iterate those account numbers and pass it into required parameters in your queries in the procedure.

Comment: Got it :) thanx for the help @jinesh Shah

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is defined as a procedure that runs in response to an insert, update, or delete statement. It will run every time you perform one of those DML operations. You cannot schedule a trigger to run once a day.

From the [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) (but applicable to all databases that implement triggers):

> A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts, updates, or
>   deletes rows in the associated table. These row operations are trigger
>   events.

Instead, you need to look for a task scheduler. Each OS will have its own or you could find a third-party scheduler software.

Comment: This is correct. a DML is needed to "trigger" something. I believe the task schedulers are called Jobs.